# No Firefox UI if launched during boot-up

Tags: windows-xp, process, user-interface, firefox-3.6

At work I'm using Windows XP SP2. What I've noticed is if I launch Firefox **while Windows hasn't finished booting up**, it launches the `firefox.exe` process but fails to launch the associated UI i.e. there's no Firefox window at the end of it.

The only way to resolve this is to kill the `firefox.exe` process and re-launch Firefox.

Has anyone else experienced this kind of behavior?

**Update**: I'm using Firefox 3.6

Comment: Why was this question made community-wiki? FAQ(http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: @heavyd - in this case it was likely accidental.  but even if a question doesn't *need* to be community wiki, that doesn't mean a user can't *choose* it if they want.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this occasionally even with Firefox 3.6, on XP SP3; but usually it's enough to double-click again on the Firefox icon - that gets the UI displayed. Eventually.

Patience.

I assume that when I do this, Windows is running code in the same Firefox instance (since I don't have -no-remote set in the shortcut) but that's its re-running some initialisation code that was executed too early the first time.

I'm not too familiar with Windows process execution, or how Firefox initialises, so this answer is intentionally vague.

You'd think that Windows would either honour the CreateWindow request (or whatever Firefox does) or return an error so that the application knows that something's up. Maybe Windows silently fails. Or maybe Firefox silently ignores an error from Windows that "should never happen".

Answer (score -1):

Yes. I experienced this behavior when I was on windows vista with Firefox 3.5 or 3.4. Now I don't see it any more.

I guess or windows-7 don't have this problems. or, more likely, that it was fixed in Firefox 3.6.

Comment: Incidentally I'm using Firefox 3.6 at work, so the problem seems to be with Windows, not the poor Firefox executable.